# Rails 3.2 nested route on simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, nested-routes

I have a nested route between object1 and object2. When I try to edit an object2 I  got an error:

```
undefined method `object2_path' for #<#Class:0x000000040b2fa8>:0x000000029c8810>.
```

config/routes.rb

```
resources :object1 do
  resources :object2
end
```

view/object2/_form.html.haml:

```
= simple_form_for [@object1, @object2] do |f|
```

If I change the view to add a specific url like:

```
= simple_form_for [@object1, @object2], :url => object1_object2_path, do |f|
```

then the edit works but new doesn't.

If instead of object1_object2_path as url I set object1_object2s_path (the index path), both views are rendered  but edit fails because the form is pointing to the wrong url (that's obvious, is just a part of the tries I did).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems `@object1` is `nil` in this case:

```
simple_form_for [@object1, @object2] do |f|
```

So rails attempts to use the `object2_path` instead of `object1_object2_path`. Try to check the value of `@object1`.

Comment: You were absolutely right. For edit action I wasn't setting @object1. BTW I didn't know this rails behavior. Thanks Mikhail.